# Syntax sugar for assigning an object property

Tags: c#, syntax, initialization

I recently encountered a nice feature in `C#`. I don't know its name, but somehow it'll free us from typing `new ClassName()` thing. Which means the following snippet:

```
var myObject = new MyObjectClass 
{
   MyProperty = new MyPropertyClass
   {
     StrValue = "Foo"
   }
}
```

Could be changed to:

```
var myObject = new MyObjectClass 
{
   MyProperty = 
   {
     StrValue = "Foo"
   }
}
```

There is no `new MyPropertyClass` anymore right?
BTW: I'm using `C# 8.0`.
**Question:** What is this feature's name? Although the details could be googled knowing the feature's name, but it would be nice if someone has a brief overview.

Comment: The two examples are not equivalent. The second tries to set the `StrValue` of an existing `MyPropertyClass`, which will result in a `NullReferenceException` if `MyProperty` isn't initialised.

Comment: Do you mean this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new?

Comment: @Johnathan Barclay You right (my bad), since when this syntax is added? BTW, please write it as an answer, so I can mark it as a correct one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mean [`Target-typed new expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new). This feature allows omitting type specification for constructors when the type is known or when it can be inferred from usage.

The feature will be in C# 9.0 which is part of the [.NET 5 development platform](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/). The scheduled release time is November 2020.

The new syntax will look like:

```
        public class Person
        {
            public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        }
    
        public class Vehicle
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        var person = new Person()
        {
            Vehicle = new ()
            {
               Name = "Car"
            }
        };
```